# Explain nn.LookupTable usage in Torch in the the most simple way possible

Tags: lua, lookup-tables, torch

I am currently dealing with an index error relating to the nn.LookupTable module in Torch. I'm sure I can fix it but I think part of my problem related to the fact that I don't really understand what an nn.LookupTable is conceptually doing.

Particularly, I am trying to understand what the usage of nn.LookupTable is in the context of Element-Research's RNN package. See example from, [here](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn/blob/master/examples/nested-recurrence-lstm.lua)

```
    -- The example demonstates the ability to nest AbstractRecurrent instances.
-- In this case, an FastLSTM is nested withing a Recurrence.
require 'rnn'

-- hyper-parameters 
batchSize = 8
rho = 5 -- sequence length
hiddenSize = 7
nIndex = 10
lr = 0.1

-- Recurrence.recurrentModule
local rm = nn.Sequential()
  :add(nn.ParallelTable()
      :add(nn.LookupTable(nIndex, hiddenSize)) 
      :add(nn.Linear(hiddenSize, hiddenSize))) 
   :add(nn.CAddTable())
   :add(nn.Sigmoid())
  :add(nn.FastLSTM(hiddenSize,hiddenSize)) -- an AbstractRecurrent instance
  :add(nn.Linear(hiddenSize,hiddenSize))
  :add(nn.Sigmoid())
```

Can someone please explain conceptually what a LookupTable does in Torch and why it is important? Bonus points if you can explain how it is being used here in this example.

Edit: I have also read [this](http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/nn/index-2-5-5.html) tutorial and though I mostly understand what is going on I cant for the life of my understand why a LookupTable would be useful here.